# Apache Virtual Hosts - Map different paths of the same domain to different sites

Tags: networking, server, apache2

I a running Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)

I want to use only one domain name.

I would like to map different sites to different paths after the domain name.

For example:

mydomain.com/test001 maps to /var/www/test001/public

mydomain.com/test002 maps to /var/www/test002/public

I've already tried many different virtual host configurations but none of them worked.

so now I am trying to map mydomain.com/test002 to /srv/public , as below:

Alias /test002 /srv/test002/public_html

```
<Directory /srv/test002 /public_html>

   Order Allow,Deny

   Allow from all

   Options FollowSymLinks

</Directory>
```

the first site woks but the second site index page only works and if I tried to redirect to another page it will give '404 page not found'

the .htaccess of the second site is :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /test002/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule !.(js|css|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|map)$ index.php [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets)
```

It is very  weird, I have been working on it all day and no solution yet and couldn't find anything helpful on the web.

can anyone help me please?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you aren't using `Alias /test001/ /var/www/html/test001/public/` to do this?

Comment: I tried doing as above but I get 'permission denied ' as a response even when all the permissions needed are granted

Comment: I am unfamiliar with `/srv` as a directory. If this is one that you've created on your own, you will want to ensure that AppArmor recognises it as a location for Apache to read/write. Otherwise, Apache will be limited to only the directories within `/var/www` 

Comment: you can enable /srv directory in apache.conf by uncommenting this code:         <Directory /srv/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by adding to the options in the directory :

Options +Indexes +followSymLinks

so it looks like this:

<Directory /srv/test002/public_html>

Order Allow,Deny

Allow from all

Options +Indexes +followSymLinks

</Director